# RFCOMM Before Android 2.0?

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-ndk, rfcomm

I have several apps which I wrote using the standard SDK. They all connect to RFCOMM devices using bluetooth, so at present, I can only support devices which are 2.0 or newer.

What options are available for backporting a bluetooth app to pre-2.0 apps while re-writing as little code as possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[android-bluetooth](http://code.google.com/p/android-bluetooth/) is the only thing I have seen on the matter.